# Careers 2.0 Address Changes

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs, geography

When I enter my location as "Ashdod, Israel" it is converted to "Emunim, Israel", which is not even close. Why not just trust me on knowing where I am?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ceE.jpg]

Comment: Are you sure Ashdod hasn't moved?

Comment: Are you sure you know where you are?

Comment: Funny. It shows Emunim, but when you go back to the edit is still displays Ashdod. Strangely, the country drop down is not sorted alphabetically either (look for United Kingdoms - just after Gabon!)

Comment: I don't like to be told where I live if I knew better. When I enter your two cities in google, I get a 9 km location difference thus Ashdod is the bigger one - do you mean these? http://goo.gl/maps/TqVYW

Comment: Gabon has country code GA and United Kingdom has GB, so it *is* kind of alphabetically sorted.  :-)

Comment: @Shegit: These are the places. If it was the other way around, I'd have accepted it as 'close enough', but as it is, it's like correcting 'Boston' to 'Salam'.

Comment: @BoPersson - Kinda... but not in the drop down where a user would expect it to be.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I like my maps in english: http://goo.gl/maps/9B5Kp :-P

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with our geocode provider, you can see the issue [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22Ashdod%22). I’ve put in a request on their forums for a correction.

Comment: Interesting, it has both results but ranks Emunim as the better one.